# Picker selection

Tags: swiftui, picker

I have following view:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ChangePropertiesView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings
    @State var currentPost: Post

    @State private var departmentSelectionId = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            LabeledContent("Priority",value: currentPost.prioritytitle)

            HStack {
                Text("Department:")
                
                Spacer()

                Picker("Change department", selection: $departmentSelectionId) {
                    ForEach(settings.departmentList, id: \.id) { department in
                        Text(department.title)
                    }
                } .onAppear(perform: {
                    updateDepartmentSelection()
                })
            }
        }
    }   
    
    func updateDepartmentSelection() {
        for department in settings.departmentList {
            if department.id == currentPost.departmentid {
                departmentSelectionId = department.id
                debugPrint("Setting correct department to: \(departmentSelectionId)")
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm receiving the department info by fetching appropriate data using api and Picker complains, that departmentSelectionId = 0 isn't correct because it doesn't exists. The error is:

> "Picker: the selection "0" is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results."

I'm using that onAppear function to correctly select department, but the error irritates me. Is there a way how to silence it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the `Picker` is probably using the ids of the items as defined in the `ForEach`, which seems to work although I couldn't find it documented. To make it more explicit, you might want to add a tag to the picker items inside the `ForEach`:

```swift
Text(department.title)
    .tag(department.id)
```

Tags are [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker) as being unnecessary if the option items implement `Identifiable`. If this is the case, you don't need to identify the `id` in the `ForEach` either.

However, this probably won't fix it - you are still going to get the error unless there is a department with an id of 0. You need to set the initial value of `departmentSelectionId` to a valid department id, instead of to 0. One possibility would be to set it to the id of the first department in the collection:

```swift
@State private var departmentSelectionId =
    settings.departmentList.first?.id ?? 0
```

Alternatively, a simpler option might be to exclude the `Picker` from the `HStack` until the state variable has a valid value:

```swift
HStack {
    // initial content as before

    if departmentSelectionId > 0 {
        // Picker here
    }
}
.onAppear {
    updateDepartmentSelection()
}
```

BTW, in the function `updateDepartmentSelection`, you might want to break out of the loop once you have identified the correct id.

Comment: I went with the "if condition" even I don't know if it is really needed. Thanks for help indeed.